# Tasks created in Data Loader don't send emails or create notifications

Tags: email, data-loader, tasks, task-notifications

I have a lot of tasks to create so I am using the Data Loader to speed up the process. However, when the tasks are imported, the user they're assigned to doesn't get a notification within Salesforce nor do they get an email alerting them to the task, but when I manually create the exact same task through the SF GUI, they get a notification and an email. Why is this? Can it be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way of doing this without having to write some apex code(trigger).
Event though [Which field represents the “Send Notification Email” checkbox present on the Task page layout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14205/which-field-represents-the-send-notification-email-checkbox-present-on-the-tas) thread is little older it is still relevant to date.

In the meanwhile you could upvote the idea [Data loader and notification e-mails](https://success.salesforce.com/apex/ideaView?id=08730000000Hl6XAAS)

Comment: :(  Thanks, it's at least helpful to know it's not possible (easily).

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this?

The reason why is there is an [EmailHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_emailheader.htm) header which requires `triggerUserEmail`  to be `true` in order to send an email. The Data Loader does not provide this header, so no email is sent.

> Can it be fixed?

A programmer could "fix" this; the [Apex Data Loader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) is open source. However, short of the community getting around to it, it is unlikely that it will be fixed by Salesforce anytime soon. After all, this program wasn't even originally meant for public consumption, being used mainly by internal salesforce.com employees.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I could do my job without Data Loader. It's interesting that it was originally just an internal tool.

Comment: @sayv yeah, it was one of those deals where some Premier Support customers found out about it, started asking for it... one thing led to another and it was released. The Data Loader is arguably the weakest of all Salesforce data manipulation programs. It just so happens that it's probably the best of the free tools out there. Things like dataloader.io and so should be able to trigger those emails, if one were interested in paying for the service, for example.